# Processing/Java - Key pressed/Key released

Tags: java, processing

I'm building an application on Processing using NyARToolkit, but my question is not directly about NyArToolkit but about a key released() method.

The thing is, I show a card and then I can do a few things if I press different keys. I press "X" and it shows one thing, I press "Y" and it shows another thing. The problem is, it shows the info from the last key pressed all the time.

If I change my AR card, it will immediatly show the info from the last key pressed. I would like to do something to release the key, something like: just show while i'm pressing the key, or have an "ESC" to stop showing everything.

I've been reading about the keyreleased() method but I didn't figured it yet out to put it to work.

By the way my method is like this:

if(key == "c") then

else if(key =="d") then...

Comment: Strings are not compared for equality using ==, use .equals instead. Ie key.equals("c"). Remember that this is case sensitive

Comment: http://processing.org/reference/key.html Check the reference. You should be using chars instead of Strings. In other words, use ' ' instead of " " around the letters.

Answer (score 0):

How about a boolean keeping track wether you've pushed something

```
private boolean buttonIsPressed = false;
```

and inside your keyPressed

```
buttonIsPressed = true;
```

and inside your keyReleased

```
buttonIsPressed = false;
```

This way you can keep track wether it's pressed or not, using a String you can also keep track which button is being held by initializing it in your keyPressed and making it null in your keyReleased.

If I missunderstood your question let me know.

EDIT:

Reading your edit, you're making quite a big mistake there, make sure to use .equals to compare strings so if(key.equals("c")) 
Again, your question is not quite clear for me, so if I'm wrong, excuse me.